# Is every Lie group a cover of a matrix Lie group?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group. Is it necessarily the case that there is a matrix Lie group $H$ and a smooth homomorphism $p:G\to H$ which is also covering map? And if so, what can be said about the kernel of $p$?

This "fact" is mentioned in the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/64195/16107), I was hoping for a reference or sketch of the proof.

I know that there are Lie groups which are not matrix Lie groups, but that a version of Ado's Theorem says every Lie algebra is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group, and thus every Lie group is locally isomorphic to a matrix Lie group. As a novice in this area, I don't know how you would get a covering map from that.

Comment: You should add "connected." Then use the fact that a local isomorphism of connected Lie groups implies an isomorphism of their universal covering groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I am stuck on a step here. This argument shows that the universal cover of $G$ is a cover of a matrix Lie group, which means that if we consider the equivalence relation generated by "X covers Y" then $G$ is equivalent to a matrix Lie group.  How to rule out, e.g., that $G$ is covered by a matrix group but doesn't cover one?

Comment: Is is true that if $G$ is a matrix group which covers $G'$, then $G'$ is also a matrix group?  If so, then I think I can provide an answer.

Comment: I suppose another (equivalent?) way of asking my question is: Does every Lie group have a quotient by a discrete normal subgroup which is isomorphic to a matrix Lie group?

Comment: @JasonDeVito isn't this a counterexample? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236343/proving-a-quotient-of-the-heisenberg-group-is-not-a-matrix-lie-group

Comment: Yes it is!  Back to the drawing board.....

Comment: I'm not sure this is true in general. In semisimple groups we can take the adjoint group which has a faithful representation on the Lie algebra and all other groups with that Lie algebra are covers of it. But that won't work on a solvable group for example.

Comment: @Callum I am more interested in the semisimple case. Can we say that every such group covers a matrix group? I am a little confused with your comment because I know things like the universal cover of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, while obviously covering a matrix group, has no faithful finite-dimensional representation.

Comment: @IianSmythe the adjoint group of a semisimple Lie algebra is always a matrix group and then the other groups are covers of it. They won't all be matrix groups but you only wanted to see that they all cover a matrix group, no?

Comment: @Callum I was mixing up the adjoint group of the Lie algebra with the adjoint representation of the group. I think I get it now.